# HTTP Request line

Tags: http

Learning HTTP from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm)

In the URI section (third method), it says that a request to www.w3.org would open a TCP connection to port 80 and send the following request line/s:

```
GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3.org
```

At initial request, how would does the client end device know the specific .html filename to grab? If it were index.html or one of the default ones, I'd understand, but TheProject.html is not.

Comment: Quite simply the system doesn't.   The entire thing is the URL which has been requested - this can either be typed in at the command line or a link from another site (eg a search)

Answer (score 7):

When you click on a link in a web page, it has the filename that is to be requested.  Hover your mouse over the turorialspoint link you have posted:

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm
```

This translates to

```
GET /http/http_requests.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
```

In the absence of a specific file, the url would be  `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/`.  This translates to:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
```

Web servers are configured with what is called an `index` file or `default` file.  This is the file that gets served from a directory when no specific filename is requested.  Often this is `index.html` or `default.htm` or `index.php`, or multiples of these, which are tried in turn until one is found.

Comment: Cool. So how/where is this `index` or `default` file defined or configured?

Comment: In the webserver configuration. The client has nothing to do with that. The webserver should return some document when the client requests a directory (like the root directory ***/*** ). In the early days of the web, most servers would just return a directory listing, but now usually some document is returned.

Comment: @tjt263, Apache uses the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) setting. IIS from Microsoft also has a [default document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320051) setting. You can also configure the web server to generate automatically a listing of the requested directory, see for example the [`mod_autoindex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) module from Apache.